# Upgrade from SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise to SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, upgrade

We have SQL Server 2008 R2, which is in production & cannot be shutdown at this stage. I have installed SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition. Can I copy the databases, users and logins, with `.ldfs`, `.mdfs` & `.ndfs`, or use backups to restore to the server running 2016 Standard Edition?

Note that my SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise databases do not utilize any of the Enterprise features.

Comment: https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/finding-enterprise-only-features-in-your-sql-server-2008-database/  Check out that blog to see what features you are using. then look if they are available in SS2016 SP1 (a lot of enterprise available in Standard now with limitations though)

Answer (score 1):

A quick Internet search for 'sql server restore enterprise to standard' indicates this is 'theoretically' possible if you're not using 'Enterprise' features.  The only way you'll truly know is to actually attempt the restore of a backup from SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise to SQL Server 2016 Standard.

[Downgrade from SQL Server Enterprise Edition to Standard Edition](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3079/downgrade-from-sql-server-enterprise-edition-to-standard-edition/)

[Migrating a database from Enterprise to Standard Edition](https://sqlsunday.com/2016/02/06/migrating-a-database-from-enterprise-to-standard-edition/)

Comment: In terms of features, Standard and Enterprise editions are pretty much at parity since 2016sp1 - the differences that remain are licensing and artificial limits (how many cores and how much RAM each instance can use, and so on). This means that restoring from enterprise to standard is even safer than it once was.

Comment: and you definitely want to do the backup and restore method rather than the detach and attach method.

Answer (score 0):

I know it seems silly but have you tried the [Upgrade Advisor](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3688/prepare-for-an-upgrade-with-the-sql-server-2016-upgrade-advisor/)?

Comment: Thanks, but i have gone the old restore backup route, Installed MSSQL Server 2016 and Restored DB's one by one copied logins and Users and done....